# Explicit formula of Fourier Transform of $e^{-\pi x^4}$.

Tags: power-series, fourier-transform, gamma-function

The Fourier Transform of $f(x)$ is defined by
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx.$$
Let $f(x)=e^{-\pi x^{2k}},k\in\Bbb{N}$,
I can get the Fourier Transform of $e^{-\pi x^{2k}}$ with the following implicit formula:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^{2k}}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx=
\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2\pi \xi)^{2n}}
{\pi^{\frac{2n+1}{2k}}(2n)!}
\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+1}{2k}\right).$$
When take $k=1$, we know that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^{2}}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2\pi \xi)^{2n}}
{\pi^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}(2n)!}
\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right).$$
Combining $\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\sqrt{\pi}$,
where $(2n-1)!!=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots (2n-1)$,
we get $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^{2}}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx=
e^{-\pi \xi^{2}}.$$
And this is a well known result.
Here I want to know for any $k\in\Bbb{N}$, does the formula
$$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2\pi \xi)^{2n}}
{\pi^{\frac{2n+1}{2k}}(2n)!}
\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+1}{2k}\right)$$
has an explicit expression as the case $k=1$?
Any help will welcome, or some $k$, such as $k=2$, can be give an explicit expression.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mathematica can solve for : `k=1,2,3,4,5...` gives answer by  generalized hypergeometric function.